# What's the term for a piece of chopped timber wood?

Tags: word-choice

This photo shows the timber wood used in construction. This is a 4 inch by 2 inch timber wood. Is there any words or term refer to this kind of chopped piece of timber wood?

Is it clear if I say "chopped timber wood"?

[image]

Comment: We call those two by fours or 2 x 4s. No, don't say chopped timber wood. For the formal term see this: https://www.lowes.com/pd/2-in-x-4-in-x-8-ft-Stud-Hemlock-Fir-Stud-Common-1-5-in-x-3-5-in-Actual/1000057123?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-lum-_-ggl-_-LIA_LUM_124_Structural-Lumber-_-1000057123-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3Z21m7zR-AIVpsiUCR3oag6XEAQYASABEgIdIfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: If you have to refer to it, **cut** is much more idiomatic than *chopped*.  *Chopped* sounds like "with an axe or a cleaver".

Comment: Call it either timber or wood, not both.

Answer (score 1):

As a general category of building material, or when discussing a substantial quantity of material, we call this *lumber* (rather than "chopped wood"). For example we can talk about a "stack of lumber", and we buy these things at a *lumber yard* or in the lumber section of a hardware store.

A single piece of lumber is a *board*. Your example shows a 2x4 board. This is often shortened to just a "2 by 4", for example, "I will need six two-by-fours to build this box".

If it's a wide board it can also be called a *plank*. A 1x12 board is a plank. Your 2x4 would not usually be called a plank.

*Timber* can be used as a mass noun referring to whole trees that have been cut down. Or it can be used for individual logs used in construction that haven't been cut into rectangular shapes. Your example does not show a timber.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are in NZ. What you have pictured is commonly called "framing timber" or "timber framing" or it may be just referred to by it's size 90x45. Inches are not used. Using the the word "chopped" implies that it may have been cut with an axe. Also the word lumber is not used in NZ.

Answer (score 0):

The type of wood used in construction is (at least in AME) called "dimension lumber", as it is all cut to the same size and shape (within tolerances of the equipment.